# How to reference System.Web namespace?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, system.web

When i writing: "System.W...", the intellisence isn't show me "System.Web" why?
[image]

Comment: Have you built your solution after adding `System.Web`? Is it a web project?

Comment: I can't repro this in a brand new web project in VS 2010. They don't target the "Client Profile" by default. Can you give us some more information?

Comment: i just checked it.. i got intellisense. even in a console app (after adding a reference).. somthing is wrong

Comment: Just a wild guess.. @GLeBaTi, is your `DatabaseManager` class in the same project that we see in the screenshot?

Comment: @Shekhar: Right, everything is set up properly in the screenshot we've been shown. There's a reference added to `System.Web`, and ASP.NET applications don't target the Client Profile by default like their Windows counterparts. Something fishy is going on; I suspect we're being hoodwinked.

Comment: @GleBaTi have you simply tried restarting VS10.. see if things smooth out.

Comment: +1 @Cody Gray: may be he is trolling.. but i wonder then how he got that screen shot..

Comment: you know what this is fourth Intellisense problem i am seeing being asked this week on SO

Comment: This is not trolling. When i building my app, in Output window, i see: Release x86

Comment: What difference does it make what you see in your Output Window? The point is, this is absolutely **not reproducible** from the information you've given (minimal) and what eagle-eyed members of the community were able to ascertain from your screenshot. I didn't mean it was trolling, I meant that there's something fishy going on and there's not enough information provided to tell what.

Comment: http://s010.radikal.ru/i312/1102/20/a3dd56d3c05b.jpg I can't join my App_Code namespace. May be it it reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i switch Build Action(of file *.cs) from "Content" to "Compile", my program began to work.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you'd changed the "Build Action" of your source files to something other than the default. No one was ever going to guess that one. Glad to see you've got your solution though; please accept this as the answer (by clicking the checkmark outline to the left) when the system allows you to do so. That way, people will know that the issue has been resolved.

Comment: I don't changed the "Build Action" before :)

Answer (score 3):

You have no reference to the assembly. Right click your project, Add Reference and add System.Web. You might also need to switch to targeting the full framework, which is in Projetc settings under Compile, in the Advanded dialog, it's the bottom dialog.

Comment: He does have a reference too it.

Answer (score 1):

could it be because you are not in a Web Project?

what does it happen if you anyway create an object of System.Web namespace and build the project then try to edit your code?

Comment: he is in a webproject.. notice a tab for portfolio.aspx page

Comment: also it dosen' matter even if he is in a console app.. as long as he has refrence to dlls'

Answer (score 0):

> There could be various possibilities for such behavior:

1. You might have missed referencing some essential assemblies; because there is no .NET without these two things i.e `BCL(Base Class Libraries)` & `CLR(Common Language Runtime).`
2. Wrong targeting of .NET Framework version. If you target .NET 3.5 or 4 client profile, you won't see ASP.NET assemblies.Solution, go to:
   Project > Properties > Target Framework. Change it from

`".NET Framework 4 Client Profile"` to `".NET Framework 4"`

Answer (score -1):

Add a using statement as such:

```
using System.Web;
```

Comment: You should still be able to access it by writing `System.Web...`, you wouldn't need `using` for that.